# Is there a dreamforce 2013 session list?

Tags: dreamforce

Has anyone created a dreamforce 2013 session list spreadsheet that they are willing to share?

In the dreamforce chatter they've been saying that the session list will only become available when agenda builder goes live.

Answer (score 3):

The session list will be available when the Agenda Builder goes live October 10th.

Comment: I knew that. Hence why I said `the session list will only become available when agenda builder goes live` For anyone who is going with a team you need time to divvy up the sessions. I'm sure someone has taken the time to build a spreadsheet of these by now.

Comment: Yes, but I don't think the session listing gets published before then.

Answer (score 3):

If you haven't registered yet, you can view the session list here: 
http://www.salesforce.com/dreamforce/DF13/sessions.jsp

If you have, log in to the app and click on the sessions tab. Note that the room/speaker/time info has not been finalized yet.

Comment: And now dates/venues have been added. Enrollment is open as well.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a URL hack to get to a list view of the sessions. Go to https://dreamevent.my.salesforce.com/a09. You must be registered and logged in for it to work.

Answer (score 0):

You can download an excel list (.csv file format) of the 2013 Dreamforce sessions from our website here:

**http://www.kineticgrowth.com/salesforce-dreamforce-conference/**

Hope this helps!  Come by and visit our Dreamforce booth - we'd love to meet you in person.

---

Also note that there is a **StackExchange session:**

Pushing the Boundaries: The Best of Salesforce StackExchange

- Monday, November 18th: 5:30 PM - 6:00 PM

And **plans to meet:**

**[Dreamforce '13 - Let's meet!](https://salesforce.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/440/dreamforce-lets-meet)**